# The highligted row in ListView doesn't remain highlighted after scrolling

Tags: android, android-listview

I have created a listview with simplecursoradapter and made it to Highlight when any of the item is clicked on it with the following code.

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">  

<item
android:state_selected="true"
android:drawable="@color/blue" /> 

<item 
android:drawable="@color/white" />

</selector>
```

and on Item selected i have done as below.

```
list = (ListView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.title_intro_list, articleCur, FROM, TO,1);
list.setAdapter(adapter);
list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, final View view,
int position, long id) 
{
view.setSelected(true);
}
```

It's working fine ,when i select the item in listview it get selected ,
But the problem is when i scroll the listview the item selected doesn't remain highlighted.

Comment: `@Override OnScroll` maybe to put `view.setSelected(true);` there too ?

Comment: Its because adapter is reusing the positions while scrolling.Thats how list view with adapter works to save memory.

Comment: The cause of the problem is when you scroll, the listview refresh all the child views so if you want it remain "selected", get in the `getView()` method, check whether the view is selected or not. if it's selected then view.setSelected(true). That should work.

Comment: Show some code in the getView() so that we could tell you what you need to change.

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned, due to the list view recycling your views, the selected view is recycled when you scroll it off the page, which is the root cause of your problem.

You need to set the choice mode on your ListView to [CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE) using either the xml attribute `choiceMode` or the `setChoiceMode()` method. It has been awhile, but I think that automatically makes the clicked on position the selected item, but if not, you can call `setSelection(position)` on the ListView (which is the `parent` parameter) in `onItemClick`

Comment: Added `android:choiceMode="singleChoice"` but didn't work .
can you post a snippet of code .

Answer (score 0):

you should use the inner class that extends BaseAdapter ,for example:

```
    private class TicketLVAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private List<Ticket> list;
    private HashMap<String, Integer> alphaIndexer;
    private String[] sections;
    List<Ticket> ts;

    public TicketLVAdapter(Context context) {
        this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    public void setList(List<Ticket> ts) {
        this.ts = ts;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return ts.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return ts.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
//the very important method:
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder = null;//use view holder;
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.pulldown_item, null);
        holder.tv_id_num = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.num_id);
        holder.tvConsumeTime = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.time);
        holder.tvOperator = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.operator);
        holder.tvValue = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.value);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
        Ticket ticket = ts.get(position);
        if (rtApp.isOnUnload) {// onCreate()方法中清空掉failureTickets
            ArrayList<Integer> positionList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
            for (int i = 0; i < ts.size(); i++) {
                if (rtApp.failureTickets.contains(ts.get(i).getTicketID())) {
                    positionList.add(i);
                }
            }
        }
        String ticketCT = ticket.getTicketconsumeTime();
        holder.tvConsumeTime.setText(ticketCT);
        holder.numberString = "位置：" + position;
        String ticketOp = ticket.getTicketOperator();
        holder.tvOperator.setText(ticketOp);
        holder.tv_id_num.setText(position + 1 + "");
        String ticketValue = ticket.getTicketPrice();
        holder.tvValue.setText(ticketValue);
        if (rtApp.failureTickets.contains(ticket.getTicketID())
                && rtApp.isOnUnload) {
            holder.tvConsumeTime.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ff0000"));
            holder.tvOperator.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ff0000"));
            holder.tv_id_num.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ff0000"));
            holder.tvValue.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ff0000"));
        }
        return convertView;
    }

    private class ViewHolder {
        TextView tvID;
        TextView tvConsumeTime;
        TextView tvOperator;
        TextView tvValue;
        TextView tv_id_num;
        String numberString;

    }

    @Override
    public int getPositionForSection(int section) {

        String later = sections[section];
        return alphaIndexer.get(later);
    }

    @Override
    public int getSectionForPosition(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public Object[] getSections() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }
}
```