# how to update the text on click of listview items in adapter

Tags: android

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pghRl.jpg)I want that if user clicks + and - button then action performed to that particular list item in listview. In my program when I clicked first item's button then value increment and decrement also but when another items button clicked that time it consider previous items value and incerement and decrement action performed on that value .I want that each item perform their seperately. I don't know how to implement this.

Here my code:

```
public static class ViewHolder {
        TextView tv_qty;
    }

    public class ProductAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Product>  {
        ImageLoader imageLoader;
        public ProductAdapter(Context context, int resource) {
            super(context, resource);
            imageLoader = new ImageLoader(context);
        }
        @Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            Product product = getItem(position);
         //   Product product=ge
            View view;
            if (convertView == null) {
                LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
                view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.product_row, null);
            } else {
                view = convertView;
            }
            final ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            tv_row_product_name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.pname);
            tv_row_product_rate = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.price);
            tv_row_product_qty = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.productqty);
            viewHolder. tv_qty = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.userqty);
            tv_value = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView_value);
            tv_totalprice = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview_totalprice);
            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
            Log.d(Config.tag, "url : " + "uploads/product/" + product.image1);
            Picasso.with(ListViewProduct.this)
                    .load("http://www.sureshkirana.com/uploads/product/" + product.image1)
                    .into(imageView);
            imgbtnp = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.imageButton2);
            imgbtnm = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.imageButton);
            imgbtnp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    count++;
                   viewHolder. tv_qty.setText(String.valueOf(count));
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            });
            imgbtnm.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    if (count > 0)
                        count--;
                       viewHolder.tv_qty.setText(String.valueOf(count));
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            });
            view.setTag(viewHolder);
            tv_row_product_name[enter image description here][1].setText(product.productTitle);
            tv_row_product_rate.setText("Rs. " + product.productPrice + "/-");
            tv_row_product_qty.setText(product.quantity + "kg");
            tv_totalprice.setText("Rs." + product.product_amount);
            return view;
          }
    }
}
```

Comment: listview item click or button click???

Comment: you should look at this :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18119755/the-highligted-row-in-listview-doesnt-remain-highlighted-after-scrolling/18120781#18120781

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use a single variable for this purpose. Set the count as tag to your list item `viewHolder.tv_qty.setTag(count);`
and retrieve the value like `viewHolder.tv_qty.getTag();`.

Answer (score 0):

on clicking on the + or - sign get the position of the clicked item in getView and get the product object at that position and modify with the new values and again put the modified object inside same list at same position and call notifyDatasetChanged() . Hope it helps.

Answer (score -1):

Using Interface you can solve this problem. You need to update your object and then refresh you list adapter using notifyDataSetChanged().

**Custom Adapter**

```
public interface QuantityClickListener {
    void onIncrementClickListner(int position);

    void onDecrementClickListner(int position);
}

/*
 * (non-Javadoc)
 * 
 * @see android.widget.ArrayAdapter#getView(int, android.view.View,
 * android.view.ViewGroup)
 */
@SuppressLint("InflateParams")
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ListViewWrapper wrapper = null;
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
    if (null == convertView) {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_list_item, null);
        wrapper = new ListViewWrapper(convertView);
        convertView.setTag(wrapper);
    } else {
        wrapper = (ListViewWrapper) convertView.getTag();
    }
    // Schedule schedule = objects.get(position);
    Products product = mProducts.get(position);
    if (null != product) {
        wrapper.getTxtQuantity().setText("" + product.quantity);

        wrapper.getNegativeBtn().setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                quantityClickListener.onDecrementClickListner(position);
            }
        });

        wrapper.getPositiveBtn().setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                quantityClickListener.onIncrementClickListner(position);
            }
        });
    }
    return convertView;
}
```

**Activity**

```
/**
 * Initialize UI elements
 */
private void initialize() {
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
    dummyData();
    adapters = new CustomAdapters(this, 0, products);
    adapters.setQuantityClickListener(quantityClickListener);
    listView.setAdapter(adapters);
}

private QuantityClickListener quantityClickListener = new QuantityClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onIncrementClickListner(int position) {
        if (null != products && products.size() > 0) {
            Products product = products.get(position);
            product.quantity++;
            product.totalPrice = product.quantity * product.price;
            adapters.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDecrementClickListner(int position) {
        if (null != products && products.size() > 0) {
            Products product = products.get(position);
            if (product.quantity > 0) {
                product.quantity--;
                product.totalPrice = product.quantity * product.price;
                adapters.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: please, add an explanation about you answer. Post only code is not a nice way to answer.

Comment: This will help you to solve your problem. You can download the sample application from the following link,[link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ff5g0corgisacz2/Sample.apk?dl=0)